# How can I replace HTML line in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, html

I need to replace an html code in multiple posts. This is the code I am using:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'target="_top" class="text"') WHERE 'post_content'  = 'class="text"'
```

But I am getting an error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') WHERE 'post_content' = 'class="text"'' at line 1

Is there any solution to make it work properly ?

Comment: how are you executing the sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three arguments for replace, and you will also need to use `LIKE` in your `WHERE` clause or you won't get any matches. Finally you don't want single quotes around `post_content` in the `WHERE` clause.  Either use backticks or nothing.

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'class="text"', 'target="_top" class="text"')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%class="text"%'
```

Answer (score 3):

`REPLACE` takes three arguments, you only gave two. You didn't tell it what to replace the matched text with.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) for proper use of `REPLACE`. You need to provide 3 arguments:

`REPLACE(str, from_str, to_str)`

> Returns the string str with all occurrences of the string from_str
>   replaced by the string to_str. REPLACE() performs a case-sensitive
>   match when searching for from_str.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT REPLACE('www.mysql.com', 'w', 'Ww');
>         -> 'WwWwWw.mysql.com'
> ```